# Find the minimum value of $a^4+b^4+\sqrt {ab}$ if $a+b=1$.

Tags: calculus

Find the minimum value of $a^4+b^4+\sqrt {ab}$ if $a+b=1$.

My attempt:
If we put $a=b=\dfrac {1}{2}$, we get $\dfrac {5}{8}$ which is the minimum value. But are there any other methods.?

Comment: I know it's about precalculus but this question becomes simpler using partial derivatives by looking on this function as two variable function.

Comment: @Albert Einstein I answered using only precalculus (binomial theorem). Are you sure you want this solution? The calculations are quite messy.

Comment: @segevp, If its so then I can tag it as 'Calculus'.

Answer (score 3):

Note that:

$$a+b=1 \Rightarrow a^2+b^2=1-2ab \Rightarrow a^4+b^4=1+2a^2b^2-4ab.$$

If we denote $\sqrt{ab}=t$, the LHS function will be:

$$f(t)=2t^4-4t^2+t+1.$$

Noting that $0\le \sqrt{ab} \le 0.5,$ minimum will be $f(0.5)=0.625$.

Answer (score 1):

To simplify calculations, let $\,u=1-2a \iff a = \frac{1-u}{2}\,$ and $\,v=1-2b \iff b = \frac{1-v}{2}\,$, then the problem can be restated as finding the minimum value for $u+v=(1-2a)+(1-2b)=0\,$ of: $$f(u,v)=\left(\frac{1-u}{2}\right)^4+\left(\frac{1-v}{2}\right)^4+\sqrt {\frac{(1-u)(1-v)}{4}}$$

The condition gives $v=-u\,$, so in the end the problem reduces to minimizing :

$$
\begin{align}
g(u) = 8 f(u,-u) &= \frac{1}{2}\left(1-u\right)^4+\frac{1}{2}\left(1+u\right)^4+4 \sqrt {(1-u)(1+u)} \\[3px]
 &= u^4 + 6 u^2 + 1 + 4 \sqrt{1-u^2}
\end{align}
$$

Let $\,w=u^2 \in [0,1]\,$, then:

$$
h(w)=g(\sqrt{w}) = w^2+6w+1+4 \sqrt{1-w}
$$

The critical points are given by $\;h'(w)=2 w + 6 - \frac{2}{\sqrt{1 - w}}=0 \iff w^3 + 5 w^2 + 3 w - 8 = 0\,$. The latter cubic can be readily verified to have exactly one real root in $[0,1]\,$. That root can be shown to correspond to a *maximum* of $\,h(x)\,$, for example by further inspecting $\,h''(x)\,$.

Therefore the *minimum* of $\,h(x)\,$ on $\,[0,1]\,$ must be attained at either end of the interval, and $\,h(0) = 5 \lt 8 = h(1)\,$ gives the minimum at $\,w=0\iff u = 0 = -v\iff a=b=\frac{1}{2}\,$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a=\cos^2t,b=\sin^2t$ ($0\le t\le \pi/2$). Then
\begin{eqnarray}
a^4+b^4+\sqrt{ab}&=&\cos^8t+\sin^8t+\cos t\sin t\\
&=&\frac1{16}(1+\cos 2t)^4+\frac1{16}(1-\cos 2t)^4+\frac12\sin2t\\
&=&\frac1{64}\bigg(\cos8t+28\cos4t+32\sin2t+35\bigg)
\end{eqnarray}
Let
$$ f(x)=\cos4x+28\cos2x+32\sin x+35,x\in[0,\pi].$$
First $f(0)=f(\pi)=64$. Clearly
\begin{eqnarray}
f'(x)&=&-4\sin4x-54\sin2x+32\cos x\\
&=&-8\cos x(\sin3x+13\sin x-4)\\
&=&32\cos x(\sin^3x-4\sin x+1).
\end{eqnarray}
Let
$$ g(u)=u^3-4u+1, u\in[0,1] $$
and then
$$ g'(u)=3u^3-4<0, u\in[0,1]. $$
Namely $g(u)$ is decreasing in $u\in[0,1]$. Since $g(0)g(1)<0$, $g(u)=0$ has a unique root $u_0\in(0,1)$. Thus $f'(x)=0$ has three solutions
$$ x_1=\frac{\pi}{2}, x_2=\arcsin u_0,x_3=\pi-\arcsin u_0. $$
Clearly $f''(x_1)=64>0$ and hence at $x=x_1=\frac{\pi}{2}$, $f(x)$ has a local minimum $f(x_1)=40$. Note
\begin{eqnarray}
f(x_2)-f(x_1)&=&f(x_2)-f(x_1)\\
&=&8(u_0^4-8u_0^2+4u_0+8)\\
&=&8(u_0^2-2u_0-1)(u_0+3)(u_0-1)>0,
\end{eqnarray}
and hence at $x=x_1\frac{\pi}{2}$, $f(x)$ has the minimum $f(x_1)=40$. Namely $a^4+b^4+\sqrt{ab}$ has the minimum $\frac{5}{8}$ when $a=b=\frac12$.

Answer (score 0):

$b=1-a$ so,
$$
a^4+(1-a)^4+\sqrt{a(1-a)}=2a^4-4a^3+6a^2-4a+1+\sqrt{a-a^2}
$$
if you now derive this expression you have
$$
8a^3-12a^2+12a-4+\frac{1-2a}{2\sqrt{a-a^2}}
$$
You correctly suspect to find a soulution at $a=1/2$, so
$$
8\left(a-\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(a^2-a+1-\frac{1}{8\sqrt{a-a^2}}\right)
$$
When $a=1/2$ the original expression is evaluated $5/8$. The second parethesis, by graphical comparison, gives two more roots close to $a=0$ and $a=1$, where the expression's value is around $1$, so $5/8$ is confirmed as the absolute minimum.

Comment: this answer is as complicated as the two deleted answers below. Lagrange Multipier should be called in .....to help out...

Comment: I don't find this so complicated, but if other downvotes and the OP confirm it, I'll delete my approach taking no offense

Answer (score 0):

Use lagrange multiplier as told by deepsea.
The function will be
$$f(a,b)=a^4+b^4+\sqrt{ab}$$
$$g(a,b)=a+b-1$$
$$\Lambda(a,b,\lambda) = f(a,b)+\lambda g(a,b)$$
Now calculate the gradient of $\Lambda(a,b,\lambda)$ w.r.t $a,b,\lambda$ 
 and put them equal to zero
So you get
$$\frac{\partial \Lambda}{\partial a} = 4a^3+ \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{b}{a}}+\lambda = 0$$
$$\frac{\partial \Lambda}{\partial b} = 4b^3+ \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{ \frac{a}{b}}+\lambda = 0$$
$$\frac{\partial \Lambda}{\partial \lambda} = a+b-1 = 0$$
Solve these three equation (the third is the same)
Substract first two equations we get
$$4(a^3-b^3)+\frac{1}{2}(\sqrt{\frac{b}{a}}-\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}})=0$$
$$(a-b)(4(a^2+b^2+ab)+\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{ab}})=0$$
which gives $a=b$
Hence the equation will be minimum at $a=b=\frac{1}{2}$
See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier example for further query

Comment: `Hence the equation will be maximum` OP's question asked for a *minimum*. Your answer hasn't actually proved either just yet. From the wikipedia link you referenced: "*However, not all stationary points yield a solution of the original problem*". There are more steps required in order to complete a proof along this line.

Comment: it will be minimum

Answer (score 0):

Your minimum appears as one of the critical values of the Lagrange function
$$\Lambda(a,b,t,\lambda_1,\lambda_2) = a^4+b^4+t+\lambda_1 (a+b-1)+\lambda_2 (ab-t^2)$$
$$\frac{\partial \Lambda}{\partial a}-\frac{\partial \Lambda}{\partial b}=\lambda_2(b-a)-4(b^3-a^3)=0$$
$a=b$ solves this equation. Assuming that $a\neq b$ then
$$\lambda_2-4(a^2+ab+b^2)=0\tag 1$$
From $$\frac{\partial \Lambda}{\partial \lambda_1}=\frac{\partial \Lambda}{\partial \lambda_2}=0$$ we conclude that
\begin{align}
a^2&=a-t^2\\
b^2&=b-t^2
\end{align}
When we use this in $(1)$ it follows that
$$\lambda_2-4(a^2+ab+b^2)=\lambda_2-4(1-t^2)=0\tag 2$$
Finally we use
$$\frac{\partial \Lambda}{\partial t}=-2\lambda_2t+1=0$$ by multiplying $2t\neq 0$ with $(2)$ to obtain the cubic univariat equation in $t$
$$2t\lambda_2-8t+8t^3=8t^3-8t+1=0$$
This is the derivative of the univariat polynomial presented by Farrukh Ataev if we identify $t$ as the positive solution to $t^2=ab$.
All roots of this cubic are real but pretty messy. Only one of these roots leads to real solutions for $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score -1):

To prove that the minimum of the function is at $\frac{5}{8}$, let us assume that we have a positive real number $k$, that is the absolute value of difference between $a$ or $b$ and $\frac{1}{2}$. Any other pairs of solutions can be represented as $(0.5+k)^4 + (0.5-k)^4 + \sqrt{(0.5+k)(0.5-k)}$.

Using the binomial theorem, we have:
$$(0.5+k)^4 = [(1)(0.5)^4 (k)^0 + (4)(0.5)^3(k)^1 + (6)(0.5)^2(k)^2 + (1)(0.5)^1 (k)^3$$

$$(0.5-k)^4 = [(1)(0.5)^4 (k)^0 + (4)(0.5)^3(-k)^1 + (6)(0.5)^2(-k)^2 + (1)(0.5)^1 (-k)^3 + (4)(0.5)^0(-k)^4]$$

The terms that have $1$st, $3$rd powers cancel, leaving:

$$(0.5+k)^4+(0.5-k)^4 = [(2)(0.5)^4 (k)^0+ (12)(0.5)^2(k)^2 + (2)(0.5)^0(-k)^4]$$
$$=2*\frac{1}{16} + 12*\frac{1}{4}*k^2 + 2*k^4$$
$$=2k^4+3k^2+\frac{1}{8}$$

The last term $\sqrt{(0.5+k)(0.5-k)}$ can be simplified into $\sqrt{-k^2+0.25}$ by the difference of squares.

Adding the terms together gives:
$$=(2k^4+3k^2+0.125) + (\sqrt{-k^2+0.25})$$

Since the derivative of $2k^4+3k^2+0.125$ is larger than $-k^2+0.25$, it follows that $2k^4+3k^2+0.125$ is larger than $\sqrt{-k^2+0.25}$, so the first function grows faster.

The first term has a minimum of $0.125$ when $k=0$, and also when $k=0$ the function $\sqrt{-k^2+0.25}$ evaluates to $0.5$, $0.5 + 0.125 = 0.625$, so the function is at is minimum when $a,b $ = $0.5+0$, or when $a,b = 0.5$.

Comment: $\sqrt{-k^2+.25}$ has a *maximum* at $k=0\,$, so it doesn't follow that the *minimum* of the sum is attained there.

Comment: Notice how the first two terms grow faster than the last. Since the k-values must be the same for both terms to find the minimum, so even if $k=0$ is the maximum of the last term, that result still gives the minimum value of the entire function.

Comment: `Notice how the first two terms grow faster than the last` Maybe so, but that needs to be proved, it's not obvious enough to hand-wave it.

Comment: I added the extra step. It seemed really intuitive to me without the step, but @dxiv is it clearer now?

Comment: `Since the derivative ... is larger` Well, they are both $0$ at $k=0$. Sorry, but that's still not a proof.

Comment: What do you suggest I do to fix that section then?

Comment: You reduced it to a function in one variable, so you could look for the minimum of that function for $k \in [-1/2,1/2]$ the usual way. May help with calculations if you substituted $k^2=t \in [0,1/4]\,$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59493/discussion-between-toby-mak-and-dxiv).